# Making a full stack app and GettingCORS policy error saying Access control allow origin header is not present but i've passed it

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-chrome, cors

Getting the following error :-
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5001/fullstack-app-feb-23-reactjs/us-central1/app/api/users/jwtVerfication' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

in my index.js i've passed Access-Control-Allow-Origin this header still it is saying not present

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
require("dotenv").config();

const serviceAccountKey = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Body parser for our JSON data
app.use(express.json());

// cross orgin
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});


// Firebase credential
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKey),
});

// api endpoints
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.send("helllo world");
});

const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

initailly it was running fine , no error was shown but due to some reasons i had to close my browser and when i reopened it and started the scripts it is showing error.

i tried searching in stackoverflow and few other websites , and used their methods but nothing is working
i was expecting no cors errors because initailly it was working fine

Comment: If you use Express's CORS middleware, you should **not** also manually set CORS response headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, here).